# how to import my module into python console?

Tags: python, import, digital-ocean

In my DigitalOcean droplet,i have installed my python3 this way:

```
sudo apt-get install make gcc  
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.0/Python-3.4.0.tgz  
tar xf Python-3.4.0.tgz -C /usr/local/src/  
cd /usr/local/src/Python-3.4.0/  
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3.4  
make  
make install  
ln -s /usr/local/python3.4/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3
```

when i upload a python file named down.py into the position with putty:

```
/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/down.py
```

why can't import the module with command:

```
import down
```

or

```
import down.py
```

or

```
import /usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4/down.py ?
```

Comment: Notwithstanding the fact that you should not place your python files in the main python directories, is `/usr/local/python3.4/lib/python3.4` in your [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables)?

Answer (score 5):

Copy down.py file to the current folder. This way you can import it as:

```
import down
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but solved it by changing sys.path

sys.path.append("/path/to/my/module/folder")

So if the module is in the current directory, you might need

sys.path(".")